# Scalac Memory Usage

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

I've been trying to compile the NeHe tutorial for scala ([link](http://code.google.com/p/jogl-scala-nehe/source/browse/demos/Lesson01.scala)) and scalac (2.9.0, linux) uses up all my ram and then some. I basically can't compile it.

Why does it use so much ram?

Is there a workaround?

Cheers,
Lucas

Comment: That's curious. About how much RAM does it eat? Might be worth a shot trying soon to be released Scala 2.9.1. http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10743 I haven't had trouble compiling JOGL programs with the default memory allocation.

Comment: As Kipton suggests, numbers and other details will help here.  How much memory is on your system? Are you specifying an `-Xmx` param or leaving this at the default? Are you getting an `OutOfMemoryException`, a `StackOverFlowException`, or running out of PermGen space?

Comment: I'm running it on my netbook, which has about 500m free plus swap. It just ends up filling my swap space to the point where my system stops responding  - I guess it might start again - but it takes more than 15mins if it does. So in practice, it doesn't compile, though it might in theory. Maybe the answer is to use a better computer, but it just seemed like a lot of memory to use up.

Comment: Think its a problem involving the combination of scalac and my laptop. Not quite sure what the problem is still.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to increase the amount of memory available by setting JAVA_OPTS to -Xmx1024m